# Accessing AWS S3 files ONLY from the Android app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I'm currently developing an Android app that could **read** and **upload** to AWS S3 storage.

S3 files should be accessed by all users only through the app without any user login information.

I've searched for Amazon Cognito, IAM and STS documentation, but since there are so many options, I don't know which one should I follow for my project.

In short:

1. S3 bucket files should be accessed ONLY from the app by all app users.
2. App users should be able to access S3 bucket files without singing in. (Temporary access)

**EDIT**

I had a working solution with hard-coded Key and Secret Key that allowed only app users to access the S3 bucket. Problem is that Google sent me an email about leaked AWS credentials:

Leaked AWS Credentials
Your app(s) expose Amazon Web Services credentials.

I followed this guide to set it up: https://grokonez.com/android/uploaddownload-files-images-amazon-s3-android

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want _all users_ of the app to be able to access the files, or are some files specific only to certain users (eg private information/photos)? Are you worried about people potentially reverse-engineering your app to extract credentials and therefore having access to the files, or would you be okay with that possibility? Do you have a backend service running, or have you only written an app?

Comment: I want all app users to access the images and JSON file that is in S3 bucket.

Comment: Do you have a backend service running, or have you only written an app?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally added the comment before finished writing. I only wrote the app and I don't mind the access to those files if reverse-engineered as long as my AWS account is not compromised. I had a solution before with hard-coded Key and Secret key but received a message from Google about "Leaked AWS Credentials" (Your app(s) expose Amazon Web Services credentials.) With hard-coded key and secret key I was able to read and upload, but I guess it's not safe. I followed this guide to achieve that: https://grokonez.com/android/uploaddownload-files-images-amazon-s3-android

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using CloudFront on top of S3 with OAI enabled.

Detailed document about same could be found on below link :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html